# Как закодировать строку в байты Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно получить в a2 такой же ответ, как и в переменной a, без использования b'...', a2 просто строка. Попытался что-то написать, но это не то. Как это сделать?

```
a = b'\x04;\x18/f6\x08\xcf\xa6\x83\xec\x8ew\xcf\\\x89{X1\x82\x94`"b\x1d\x96G\xe1\xabP\xa4\xf8]*tq"\x9d/3W1q\xb9f\xbd\x9f\xe8\x97\x14\xf9\xe13_.=\xdd}\x93\x8b\x10t\x9a\x9eqo\x9c\xd9\xa4\xb1'
print(a)
a2 = '\x04;\x18/f6\x08\xcf\xa6\x83\xec\x8ew\xcf\\\x89{X1\x82\x94`"b\x1d\x96G\xe1\xabP\xa4\xf8]*tq"\x9d/3W1q\xb9f\xbd\x9f\xe8\x97\x14\xf9\xe13_.=\xdd}\x93\x8b\x10t\x9a\x9eqo\x9c\xd9\xa4\xb1'
a2= bytes(a2, 'utf-8')
print(a2)
```

Ответы

```
b'\x04;\x18/f6\x08\xcf\xa6\x83\xec\x8ew\xcf\\\x89{X1\x82\x94`"b\x1d\x96G\xe1\xabP\xa4\xf8]*tq"\x9d/3W1q\xb9f\xbd\x9f\xe8\x97\x14\xf9\xe13_.=\xdd}\x93\x8b\x10t\x9a\x9eqo\x9c\xd9\xa4\xb1'

b'\x04;\x18/f6\x08\xc3\x8f\xc2\xa6\xc2\x83\xc3\xac\xc2\x8ew\xc3\x8f\\\xc2\x89{X1\xc2\x82\xc2\x94`"b\x1d\xc2\x96G\xc3\xa1\xc2\xabP\xc2\xa4\xc3\xb8]*tq"\xc2\x9d/3W1q\xc2\xb9f\xc2\xbd\xc2\x9f\xc3\xa8\xc2\x97\x14\xc3\xb9\xc3\xa13_.=\xc3\x9d}\xc2\x93\xc2\x8b\x10t\xc2\x9a\xc2\x9eqo\xc2\x9c\xc3\x99\xc2\xa4\xc2\xb1'
```

Comment: a2.encode() попробуй

Comment: Не получается, там вообще что-то страшное

Comment: Ах да это же строка сейчас ещё подумаю

Comment: А вообще что в a2 содержится?

Comment: bytes, это, вроде, называется)) Типо a2 это тоже самое, что a, только строка

Comment: Фрагмент чего и откуда в его получаете?))

Comment: Так, я получаю строку b'...' и её надо преобразовать к типу bytes

Comment: Получаю из файла txt

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110028/discussion-between--and-jairman).

Comment: Преобразуйте файл в bin.